# Confused about assumption in math

Tags: linear-algebra

I will express my confusion through an example:

Exercise: Suppose $W$ is a complex inner product space. Prove that
$$
\langle v,w\rangle = \frac{||v+w||^2 - ||v-w||^2 + ||v+iw||^2i - ||v-iw||^2i}{4}.
$$

Proof: Assume that $W$ is a complex inner product space with the inner product $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle$. Let $||\cdot||$ be the induced norm.

Take $v,w\in W$, $\langle v,w\rangle = a + bi$ for some $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$.
$$
\frac{||v+w||^2 - ||v-w||^2}{4} = \frac{\langle v,w\rangle + \langle w,v\rangle}{2} = a = ~\text{real}~\langle v,w\rangle
$$
$$
\frac{||v+iw||^2i - ||v-iw||^2i}{4} = \frac{||v+iw||^2 - ||v-iw||^2}{4}i = ~\text{real}~\langle v,iw\rangle\cdot i
$$
$$
= bi
$$
Therefore,
$$
\langle v,w\rangle = a + bi = \frac{||v+w||^2 - ||v-w||^2 + ||v+iw||^2i - ||v-iw||^2i}{4}.
$$

My question is: why can we assume that $\langle v,w\rangle = a + bi$ when we don't know the exact value of $\langle v,w\rangle$? Is it that the inner product is given and $v$ and $w$ are chosen vectors so $\langle v,w\rangle$ has a value?

I know my question is very basic but recently I am very confused about this kind of things..

Thanks.

Comment: Because $\langle v,w\rangle$ is a complex number, thus equals $a+bi$ for some $a,b\in \mathbb R$

Answer (score 3):

This is a fine question.

You asked

> why can we assume that $\langle v, w \rangle = a + bi$"

but this is not an assumption at all! We are not supposing anything new that we didn't know before. Here's what we know:

1. $\langle v, w \rangle$ is a complex number
2. every complex number is equal to $a + bi$ for some $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$

Therefore, $\langle v, w \rangle$ is equal to $a + bi$ for some $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$. Indeed, we do not know the exact value of $\langle v, w \rangle$ but we also don't know what $a$ and $b$ are! All we can say is that, whatever complex number $\langle v, w \rangle$ is, it can be written as $a + bi$ for some real numbers $a$ and $b$.